# Query of Facebook events for fan page is returning no results (works for other pages)

Tags: facebook-fql

The code I'm using is significantly borrowed from [The Code Of Ninja's solution](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2012/05/display-facebook-data-to-your-website.html). The code worked fine for months and one day just stopped working. When I plug another page's id into the code, it works just fine. I don't even know how to troubleshoot this...

The FB page's id is "149034208446092". There are no upcoming events for the page, but the past events (of which there are many) are not displaying either (which they should, and did with other page IDs I tested).

NOTE: All relevant code is on the link above. Mine varies slightly, but for testing purposes I've been using an exact copy of his solution.

Query for past is here:

```
SELECT name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description, eid 
FROM event 
WHERE end_time < now() 
AND eid 
IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 149034208446092 ) 
ORDER BY start_time DESC
```

Comment: @mods: I've been trying to post this in the Facebook section for about 5 minutes but it keeps throwing an error saying I need to include a FB tag to post there (which I had been doing). Feel free to migrate.

Comment: I would create an event with date in the future for this page just to see if the problem only exists with displaying events of the past. Maybe it is just a Facebook bug not returning any past events if there are zero future ones.

Comment: @Justus, I'll work on that. I don't have access to the page currently, but I've asked the owner to set that up for me. However, even while there were still upcoming events, the past events began to disappear from the listing (not all, but it was returning maybe 1 or 2 out of 50+).

Comment: @Justus, just got access and tested. New event is showing, but past events are not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known [Facebook bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165109696955100). The only thing you can do is to go to the bug and mark two things:

1. Click **yes** and fill out the form next to **Does this repro describe your
   issue?**
2. Subscribe to the bug.